# C# Windowsサービスプログラムを引数を変えて、複数起動することは可能ですか？

Tags: c#, windows, .net

タイトルの件、C#でWindows OS上で同一の実行ファイル(.exe)のサービスプログラムを起動し、引数等を変更することで動作内容がことなる複数のサービスを起動したいと考えております。

このようにWindowsサービスプログラムを引数を変えて、複数起動するは可能ですか？

OSは、Windows 10、Windows Server 2016を想定しております。
.NET Frameworkは4.6.2以上です。

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: これ [同じバイナリを複数のWindowsサービスとして動かす](https://blog.jhashimoto.net/entry/2017/09/11/124851) を試してみてください。

Comment: 引数も同じ sc コマンドで、記事はこちら。[サービスの起動時に引数を入れたい～VS2015](http://blog.syo-ko.com/?eid=2285)

Comment: ありがとうございます。サービスをサービス名を変えて複数登録し、バイナリや設定ファイルをコピーすればそれぞれの動作設定で複数サービス起動できる。サービスを複数登録し、同じバイナリであっても、引数をサービス毎にコマンドで設定すれば、同じバイナリで引数を変えたサービスを作成できると理解しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

タスクマネージャー等、プロセス一覧で`svchost.exe`を見かけたことはないでしょうか？ それぞれ異なるサービスとして登録すれば、同一の実行ファイルであってもサービスとして起動できます。

質問文で明示されていませんが、サービスを１つだけ登録し、それを引数を変えて複数起動することはできません。

また、プログラムが提供する内容次第ではありますが、今はサービスよりもタスクスケジューラーに登録し、必要なタイミングで適宜起動する方式が推奨されています。

Comment: プログラムの要件として、入力ファイルが作成されてから秒単位のオーダーで読込たいため、タスクスケジューラではなく、サービスにしようと考えております。タスクスケジューラで秒単位の間隔で繰り返し起動することはできないと認識しております。